# question on Riemann's 1859 paper, page 2

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, math-history, riemann-zeta

[This](https://www.claymath.org/sites/default/files/ezeta.pdf) is the paper I am referring to.

(After fighting through page one with success) I don't get the start of page 2 at all. I don't understand the motivation and connection to the previous expression and I also don't fully understand what is going on. He seems to suggest that the curve integral

$$ \int_{\mathcal{C}} \frac{(-x)^{s-1}}{e^{x-1}} \mathrm{d}x =(e^{-\pi s i } - e^{\pi si}) \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^{x-1}} \mathrm{d}x $$

For $\mathcal{C}=\lim_{R\to\infty}\mathcal{C}_R$ with $\mathcal{C}_R = \{z|z = R (\cos{\varphi + i \sin{\varphi}), 0\le\varphi<2\pi, R\in\mathbb{R^+}} \}$

1. Is this expression the correct interpretation of the text passage?
2. How to perform this calculation?
3. What is the motivation of this step?

Comment: No, it is for $\Re(s) > 1$, with $f(x)=e^{-x}$ and after with $f(x)=1/(e^x-1)$ $$(-e^{i\pi s}+e^{-i\pi s}) \int_0^\infty x^{s-1}f(x)dx$$ $$=\int_\infty^0 (e^{i \pi }x^{s-1}f(x)dx+\int_0^\infty (e^{-i \pi }x^{s-1}f(x)dx=\int_C (-z)^{s-1}f(z)dz$$ where $C$ encloses $[0,\infty)$

Comment: Sure, was a typo I dropped the "phase factor".

Comment: If your intention is working through the whole paper, then https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.02301 might help.See also https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-91482-4

Comment: Thank you very much @reuns (once again) and _at_franz_lemmereyer (of course I want through the whole paper)!